# Fullcalendar - passing parameters to json page

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I'd like to post a variable to my page that generates the events, so I can do something like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE userid = " . £id);
```

I'm currently using:

```
eventSources: [

// your event source
{
url: 'json-events.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {
id: userid
},
error: function() {
alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
}
}

// any other sources...

]
```

However, none of the events are shwoing up, I don't get an error though.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

Used a pound sign instead of a dollar sign in the query! :D